# Tor gets connected with Windows but not with Tail (with the same bridges)

Tags: configuration, tails, bridge, pluggable-transports

I don't really understand why I have this problem.
I managed to get TorR connected with bridges with no problem at all with Windows 7, but with Tails it is impossible. I use the same configuration with the same bridges, on the same computer, LAN connected.

Here is the log with Tail:

```
03/03/2016 23:17:14.800 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
03/03/2016 23:17:15.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
03/03/2016 23:17:15.700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
03/03/2016 23:17:15.700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061 
03/03/2016 23:17:15.700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062 
03/03/2016 23:17:15.700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
03/03/2016 23:17:15.700 [NOTICE] Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
03/03/2016 23:17:15.700 [NOTICE] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
03/03/2016 23:17:15.700 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "/etc/tor/torrc.orig.1" 
03/03/2016 23:17:16.100 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
03/03/2016 23:17:18.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
03/03/2016 23:17:18.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
03/03/2016 23:18:01.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to XX.XXX.XX.XX:XXXXX ("server rejected connection") 
03/03/2016 23:18:17.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
03/03/2016 23:18:17.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
03/03/2016 23:18:17.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
03/03/2016 23:18:17.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061 
03/03/2016 23:18:17.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062 
03/03/2016 23:18:17.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
03/03/2016 23:18:17.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
03/03/2016 23:18:17.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
03/03/2016 23:18:17.400 [NOTICE] Closing old DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
03/03/2016 23:18:17.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
03/03/2016 23:18:17.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061 
03/03/2016 23:18:17.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062 
03/03/2016 23:18:17.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
03/03/2016 23:18:48.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
03/03/2016 23:18:48.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
03/03/2016 23:18:48.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
03/03/2016 23:18:48.900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
03/03/2016 23:18:48.900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061 
03/03/2016 23:18:48.900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062 
03/03/2016 23:18:48.900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
03/03/2016 23:18:48.900 [NOTICE] Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
03/03/2016 23:18:48.900 [NOTICE] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
03/03/2016 23:19:33.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to XX.XXX.XX.XX:XXXXX ("server rejected connection") 
03/03/2016 23:19:48.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
03/03/2016 23:19:48.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
03/03/2016 23:19:48.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
03/03/2016 23:19:48.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061 
03/03/2016 23:19:48.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062 
03/03/2016 23:19:48.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
03/03/2016 23:19:48.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
03/03/2016 23:19:48.700 [NOTICE] Closing old Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
03/03/2016 23:19:48.700 [NOTICE] Closing old DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
03/03/2016 23:19:48.700 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
03/03/2016 23:19:48.700 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061 
03/03/2016 23:19:48.700 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062
```

On this log you can see 2 attempt of connection, the first one went until 10% and the second nothing.

I tried different bridges but always the same issue...

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thank you

Ok as requested here are more information
Log with windows:

```
Mar 11 09:58:08.000 [notice] Tor 0.2.7.6 (git-7a489a6389110120) opening new log file.
Mar 11 09:58:08.764 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 (git-7a489a6389110120) running on Windows 7 with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1s and Zlib 1.2.8.
Mar 11 09:58:08.765 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Mar 11 09:58:08.767 [notice] Read configuration file "C:\Users\Fabrice\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc-defaults".
Mar 11 09:58:08.767 [notice] Read configuration file "C:\Users\Fabrice\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc".
Mar 11 09:58:08.777 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
Mar 11 09:58:08.777 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9151
Mar 11 09:58:08.000 [warn] Your log may contain sensitive information - you're logging more than "notice". Don't log unless it serves an important reason. Overwrite the log afterwards.
Mar 11 09:58:08.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file C:\Users\Fabrice\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip.
Mar 11 09:58:09.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file C:\Users\Fabrice\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6.
Mar 11 09:58:09.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Mar 11 09:58:09.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor 'Unnamed' (cached): $292B444C54D8CAB7345C326652D437736CEDD6AD~Unnamed at XX.XXX.XX.Xx
Mar 11 09:58:09.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor 'anonymouse' (cached): $80FCA5A349AE7E5C2C8503BFB908D4204FDB9C3E~anonymouse at XX.XXX.XX.Xx
Mar 11 09:58:09.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor 'Unnamed' (cached): $F7D29A1373E9DA9AFE30801C26E328AE721CF0A1~Unnamed at XX.XXX.XX.Xx
Mar 11 09:58:09.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor 'anonymouse' (cached): $80FCA5A349AE7E5C2C8503BFB908D4204FDB9C3E~anonymouse at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Mar 11 09:58:09.000 [notice] Delaying directory fetches: Pluggable transport proxies still configuring
Mar 11 09:58:09.000 [notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
Mar 11 09:58:09.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
Mar 11 09:58:09.000 [notice] Tor 0.2.7.6 (git-7a489a6389110120) opening log file.
Mar 11 09:58:09.000 [notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
Mar 11 09:58:16.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
Mar 11 09:58:16.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
Mar 11 09:58:29.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection
Mar 11 09:58:29.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus
Mar 11 09:58:37.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 194.132.208.103:56401 ("general SOCKS server failure")
Mar 11 09:58:42.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus
Mar 11 09:59:01.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Mar 11 09:59:01.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Mar 11 09:59:04.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Mar 11 09:59:04.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
Mar 11 09:59:05.000 [notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
Mar 11 09:59:05.000 [notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
Mar 11 09:59:08.000 [notice] Owning controller connection has closed -- exiting now.
Mar 11 09:59:08.000 [notice] Catching signal TERM, exiting cleanly.
```

`torrc` with Tails

```
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
AutomapHostsSuffixes .exit,.onion
AvoidDiskWrites 1
Bridge obfs4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx 7511D85C2D2AFF0DAEF3C9092E337175B75350CA cert=… iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx 343F50C3399BD32FC24D0309C59C7EB095527656 cert=… iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx D2A4BA27287EFDCBC80AA00B254C815E4607DA6F cert=… iat-mode=0
ClientTransportPlugin obfs2,obfs3,obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy managed
ControlListenAddress 127.0.0.1
ControlPort 9051
DNSPort 5353
HiddenServiceStatistics 0
Log info file /var/log/tor/log
WarnUnsafeSocks 0
RunAsDaemon 0
SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9050 IsolateDestAddr IsolateDestPort
SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9061 IsolateDestAddr
SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9062 IsolateDestAddr IsolateDestPort
SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9150 IsolateSOCKSAuth KeepAliveIsolateSOCKSAuth
TransListenAddress 127.0.0.1
TransPort 9040
UseBridges 1
WarnPlaintextPorts 23,109
```

Torcc with Windows

```
Bridge obfs4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx 292B444C54D8CAB7345C326652D437736CEDD6AD cert=… iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx F7D29A1373E9DA9AFE30801C26E328AE721CF0A1 cert=… iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx 80FCA5A349AE7E5C2C8503BFB908D4204FDB9C3E cert=… iat-mode=0
DataDirectory C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor
GeoIPFile C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6
Log notice file c:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Tor Browser\notice.log
HiddenServiceStatistics 0
UseBridges 1
```

Indeed there are many differences between those last two but I am not familiar enough with all those options to understand what's wrong.

Comment: When was the last time you tried these same bridges on Windows 7 + Tor? Do they still work now?

Comment: Yes they still work perfectly with windows 7.

Comment: What kind of pluggable transport do these bridges use (example: obfs4)? Are you sure that your version of Tails supports that flavor of pluggable transport? (By the way, you are including your bridge address in your logs -- maybe you didn't want to do that, but also the more details you provide here, the more likely people are to be able to help.)

Comment: Yes I am using obfs4 and I am using the last version of Tail (2.0.1) which supports obfs4. Ok I edited my log to hide the bridges.

Comment: Maybe it is important but I live in CHINA.

Comment: can you please post yor windows tor log? and torrc files for both cases. This will clarify your question technically

Comment: Ok done I added them

Comment: OK, the first problem may be the `ls -la /usr/bin/obfs4proxy` - make sure it has 755 or 555 mode, so **everybody** can execute it. Also it is a good practice to `chown` it to the same user you're running Tor under. As far as I can see, you're using different bridges due to the keys. Try to use exactly the same ones on both OSes. Also add `GeoIPv6File` and `GeoIPFile` to your Tails `torrc`. Also if you're using hosts automapping you **must** specify a subnet for mapping, and I can't see it in your `torrc` : add `VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 10.192.0.0/10` to your config to specify *where to map hosts

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually the bridges are different because I tried many, including the ones that work with windows. After, I am using Tail, so does that mean I have to do those change each time I want to use it? And does that mean there is something wrong with the default configuration?

Comment: @Mittel I'm strongly recommend you to rely not on a default configuration, but on your config - a *very* specific one. And yes - some default values must be duplicated here, because defaults can change from version to version

Comment: The problem is that with Tail, each time I log in all the configuration should be done at the start up and it is erased when it is turn off.

Comment: @Mittel so please create a configuration and test it. The log will be an essential part in solving this question. We need to make : identical tor versions+settings test. We will see the difference and fix it

Comment: OK, I will try my best because I am not very familiar with Tail. I will let you know what happens. Thanks for the help.